# Google Drive Iframe not playin video in Safari browser

Tags: iframe, safari, google-drive-api, mobile-safari

When you add a video via  Google Drive, the video doesn't play. When you click on play, nothing happens.

The error was detected only in the Safari browser (Mac OS and iOS), on different devices. The Safari console displays the following:
[image]

In Google Drive, the video has permission and is available to everyone who has a link. The video works in Google Chrome, Firefox.

I don't use the API from Google, I only have an iframe that google itself suggests using.

My iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tYPqwtbgNp17xXNR5mZH3SdeFTcUrTHt/preview" width="640" height="480" ></iframe>
```

Video testing takes place on a clean page, without scripts and styles

Comment: You should use the direct download link from your video. You get this link with the Is of the shared file like:  'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxxxx" where xxxxxxx is your file Id. Use that in a src="" attribute

Comment: @Aerials If you insert your link, the file is downloaded. And I need the file to play in an iframe. So that the user can watch the video through the player

Comment: You could use a [<video> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video), or upload the video to Youtube and use your solution with the YT link.

Answer (score 0):

An embedded Google Drive video does play in Safari (just tested on iPhone with iOS 14.7) but only if you set '**Prevent Cross-Site Tracking**' to **OFF** in Settings, Safari, Privacy & Security.

This is probably not an option for a public website!